# Django declaring type of subclassing models

Tags: django, django-models

I need to make a "portfolio" for a site in Django im working on. I wan't the portfolio to contain both Galleries of pictures and links to sites.

I set the models up like this:

```
class PortfolioObject(models.Model):
    types = (
        (0,"gallery"),
        (1, "link")
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    oType = models.IntegerField(choices=types, default=0)
    class Meta():
        abstract = False

class GalleryObject(PortfolioObject):
    picture = models.FileField(blank=True)
    oType = 0

class LinkObject(PortfolioObject):
     link = models.URLField(blank=True)
    oType = 1
```

As you can see i want the PortfolioObject to have a "type" depending on which type it is. However this doesn't work, and the `oType` property is still 0 on `LinkObjects`.

How can i properly index the types of portfolioobjects while still having the convenience of using `PortfolioObject.objects.filter(someField=someFilter)`?

Comment: Same question(almost) but the suggestion is different. I need different models for this, a proxy model won't do

Comment: You're right, my mistake. I will retract.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the init :

```
class GalleryObject(PortfolioObject):
    picture = models.FileField(blank=True)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(GalleryObject, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.oType = 0
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

Comment: I can't use proxy here as explained in my previous comment